# Retrieving parameters in a jsp page set by f:param though h:commandLink

Tags: jsp, jsf

Am using JSF 1.2 . Am setting parameters like below,

```
<h:commandLink id="sendParam" action="#{myBean.redirectToLogin}" >
   <f:param name="userData" value="#{myBean.msg}"></f:param>
</h:commandLink>
```

I want to retrieve the parameter (userData) in a JSP page which is in some other web application. I am hitting that JSP page(lets say myJSP.jsp) from the web application where above code is written. Code is as below,

```
String link = http://myDomain/myJSP.jsp
ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
externalContext.redirect(link.trim());
```

Most importantly : A new session id will be created when the JSP page is hit. (This is because of some other requirement in my web application)

Am trying to retrieve the parameter by using below code in myJSP.jsp.

```
String requestmsg = (String) req.getParameter("userData");
```

But, this is always null.

1. Is my understanding correct about how f:param works? I mean, can we retrieve the parameters like how am trying, in some jsp page?
2. If so, will the parameter value be lost if a new session is created?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A redirect basically instructs the webbrowser to send a brand new HTTP request. The request parameters in the original JSF request are not available in that new JSP request anymore. You'd need to explicitly pass the original request parameter along that new request as well.

```
String userData = externalContext.getRequestParameterMap().get("userData");
String link = "http://myDomain/myJSP.jsp?userData=" + URLEncoder.encode(userData, "UTF-8");
externalContext.redirect(link);
```

Comment: @BalusC.. I have another scenario. Instead of hitting myJsp.jsp , this time am hitting a portlet. So, my target will be `http://myDomain/` . This invokes login portlet and calls login.jsp. Since, am not specifying the URL (something like `http://myDomain/login.jsp?userData=`) , am finding it difficult to retrive the userData values. How can I go handle this situation ? Regards,  Vikas